# 403 forbidden in dokuwiki, CSS style does not work

Tags: php, css, permission-denied, dokuwiki

I installed Dokuwiki to a web server. Instead of my local http server, I am using a web server hosting service.

The root directory of my host server is /public_html. I unzipped dokuwiki and moved it into mydomain/public_html/. I installed dokuwiki, and when I access to this url

http://mydomain/dokuwiki/

Then the main page is loaded. However, only HTML frame is shown and no CSS style works. When I pressed the f12 button, there was an error message like this..

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

According to the formal website of Dokuwiki, the CSS file does not work when PHP 5.3 is installed. They recommend users to upgrade their own PHP version. However, I am using PHP 5.6 so I guess the version is not the reason of this problem. I changed every permission of sub-directories and files in /public_html/dokuwiki directory into 777(rwx-rwx-rwx) but it didn't help me either.

Is there any other option that I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 Forbidden hints that the access denial comes from the webserver. It might be related to mod_security (See http://doku.wiki/mod_security). Contact your host for help.

Comment: I reinstalled Dokuwiki and the problem was solved. But I still don't know the reason of this problem. The only difference is this -- I installed Dokuwiki with install.php first and then changed permission at the first time, and at the second time, I switched the order of them. I am going to try to install and check more details. :)